# SSD Usage 100% at downloading | Windows 10 Bitlocker

Tags: windows-10, ssd, performance, bitlocker

if i want to write a big File or Downloading a big Steam game, my SSD gets after writing a few Gigabytes really slow. The Disk Usage is at **99 to 100%**.

Here a Screenshot from the Taskmanager:

[image: SlowSpeedDiskUsage Task Manager]

My entire **C** Partition is Encrypted with **Bitlocker** and my **free Space** on Partion **C** is about **200GB**.
I have an 1Terabyte M2 SSD.

Is it somehow possible that the SSD is **fragmented?**

What can I do to get the full SSD speed back? The M2 SSD is about one year in use but i have these problem for about 4 Months. Cpu is idling at 5-10%.

EDIT:
I have an 1000GB Crucial P1 NVMe M.2 2280 PCIe 3.0 x4 32Gb/s 3D-NAND QLC (CT1000P1SSD8) SSD

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Task Manager’s “Performance” tab with the busy disk selected when the issue occurs. The “Processes” tab is useless for most purposes.

Answer (score 0):

As others have indicated, your SSD is fragmented, but that is almost entirely irrelevant/orthogonal to your problem as fragmentation does not really affect SSD speed.

What is more likely is that you have a lower cost (QLC) SSD which has a built in high performance buffer you are exceeding (Its possible other types of SSDs have this problem but its less pronounced).

Comment: This cannot be true. Months ago i make test, downloaded huge files with 1Gbit/s Ethernet and the SSD had no problem with this. I just stoped steam Downloading and started a file downloading from https://speed.hetzner.de/ where you can test your download speed. My SSD is still slow and at 100% but only writes about 10MB/s. I am pretty shoure if i set up after i setup my complete setup, everything work fine again but i currently don't want to do this.

Comment: if found this : https://linustechtips.com/topic/1164429-stupid-slow-crucial-p1-nvme-ssd/?tab=comments#comment-13369633 maybee it has to do with some cache. But i dont know. After the first months everything runs perfectly. Even big files, no problem. So i don't know if the Cache Thing is a problem also for me???

Comment: @primeseas have you attempted local disk copies to rule out network bottlenecks? Also the Crucial P1 IS a QLC SSD - and DOES suffer slowdowns once its cache is full. The performance testing done by PC World shows exactly the behaviour described on this drive - https://www.pcworld.com/article/3337244/crucial-p1-nvme-ssd-review.html

Comment: I think it is solved. I know now that it has probably to do with the WLC architecture.